# Why does my cumulative column not work as expected?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is my query , I have a column called cum_balance which is supposed to calculate the cumulative  balance but after row number 10 there is an anamoly and it doesn't work as expected , all I notice is that from row number 10 onwards the hour column has same value. What's the right syntax for this?

```
[select
  hour,
  symbol,
  amount_usd,
  category,
  sum(amount_usd) over (
    order by
      hour asc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) as cum_balance
from
  combined_transfers_usd_netflow
order by
  hour][1]
```

I have tried removing RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW , adding a partition by hour and group by hour. None of them gave the expected result or errors

| Row Number | Hour | SYMBOL | AMOUNT_USD | CATEGORY | CUM_BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-02 23:00:00 | WETH | 227.2795 | in | 227.2795 |
| 2 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | WETH | -226.4801153 | out | 0.7993847087 |
| 3 | 2022-01-05 21:00:00 | WETH | 5123.716203 | in | 5124.515587 |
| 4 | 2022-01-18 14:00:00 | WETH | -4466.2366 | out | 658.2789873 |
| 5 | 2022-01-19 00:00:00 | WETH | 2442.618599 | in | 3100.897586 |
| 6 | 2022-01-21 14:00:00 | USDC | 99928.68644 | in | 103029.584 |
| 7 | 2022-03-01 16:00:00 | UNI | 8545.36098 | in | 111574.945 |
| 8 | 2022-03-04 22:00:00 | USDC | -2999.343 | out | 108575.602 |
| 9 | 2022-03-09 22:00:00 | USDC | -5042.947675 | out | 103532.6543 |
| 10 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | USDC | -4110.6579 | out | 98594.35101 |
| 11 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | UNI | -3.209306045 | out | 98594.35101 |
| 12 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | UNI | -16.04653022 | out | 98594.35101 |
| 13 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | UNI | -16.04653022 | out | 98594.35101 |
| 14 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | UNI | -16.04653022 | out | 98594.35101 |
| 15 | 2022-03-16 21:00:00 | UNI | -6.418612089 | out | 98594.35101 |

Comment: Please provide sample data with the described issue. Also note that in case of `range between` all rows that are ranked together according to the `order by` expressions are treated as a single group and they will have the same cumulative value. If you change it to `rows between` then the result would be different and you'll get new value per physical row

Comment: From the snowflake documentation:  "RANGE is similar to ROWS, except it only computes the result for rows that have the same value as the current row (according to the specified ORDER BY subclause). ".  Use ROWS, not Range.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with your data in all the ORDER BY values after row 10 are the same.

So if we shrink the data down a little, and use for groups to repeat the experiment:

```
with data(grp, date, val) as (
    select * from values 
    (1,'2021-01-01'::date, 10),
    (1,'2021-01-02'::date, 11),
    (1,'2021-01-03'::date, 12),
    
    (2,'2021-01-01'::date, 20),
    (2,'2021-01-02'::date, 21),
    (2,'2021-01-02'::date, 22),
    (2,'2021-01-04'::date, 23)
)
select d.*
    ,sum(val) over ( partition by grp order by date RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as cum_val_1
    ,sum(val) over ( partition by grp order by date ) as cum_val_2
from data as d
order by 1,2;
```

we get:

| GRP | DATE | VAL | CUM_VAL_1 | CUM_VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 11 | 21 | 21 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 12 | 33 | 33 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 21 | 63 | 63 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 22 | 63 | 63 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 23 | 86 | 86 |

we see with group 1 that values accumulate as we expect. So for group 2 we put duplicate values as see those rows get the same value, but rows after "work as expected again".

This tells us how this function work across unstable data (values that sort the same) is that they are all stepped in one leap.

Thus if you want each row to be different they will need better ORDER distinctness. This could be forced by add random values of literal random nature, or feeling non random ROW_NUMBER, but really they would be random, albeit not explicit, AND if you use random, you might get duplicates, thus really should use ROW_NUMBER or SEQx to have unique values.

Also the second formula shows they are equal, and it's the ORDER BY problem not the framing of "which rows" are used.

```
with data(grp, date, val) as (
    select * from values 
    (1,'2021-01-01'::date, 10),
    (1,'2021-01-02'::date, 11),
    (1,'2021-01-03'::date, 12),
    
    (2,'2021-01-01'::date, 20),
    (2,'2021-01-02'::date, 21),
    (2,'2021-01-02'::date, 22),
    (2,'2021-01-04'::date, 23)
)
select d.*
    ,seq8() as s
    ,sum(val) over ( partition by grp order by date ) as cum_val_1
    ,sum(val) over ( partition by grp order by date, s ) as cum_val_2
    ,sum(val) over ( partition by grp order by date, seq8() ) as cum_val_3
from data as d
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

| GRP | DATE | VAL S | CUM_VAL_1 | CUM_VAL_2 | CUM_VAL_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 11 | 1 | 21 | 21 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 12 | 2 | 33 | 33 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 20 | 3 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 21 | 4 | 63 | 41 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 22 | 5 | 63 | 63 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 23 | 6 | 86 | 86 |