# Copying output from Snowflake to Excel or notepad showing additional row

Tags: sql, excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to copy the output from Snowflake to Excel. For example, there are only 4 rows in Snowflake, but it becomes 5 rows with one additional row when I copied it to Excel or Notepad.

I used trim and replace statement to clean up spaces, but the extra row is still there.

Answer (score 0):

So it "works for me" the SQL come from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75461180/why-does-my-cumulative-column-not-work-as-expected/75465616#75465616)

[image]

Do you have better words, or a cut down example?

Comment: It's the first time I got this problem, most of time I can simply copy the output to excel. so I'm not sure if there is a pipeline or something else cutoff the data to the next row.

Comment: I would guess there is a new-line token in a string, that Excel is regarding..